# Getting more details by zooming in web-client?

Tags: qgis, scale, zoom, qgis-web-client, scale-factor

today I've setup a qgis server and web client on my windows machine.
[Here is my WebClient](http://aresdata.ddns.net/qgiswebclient.html?map=C:%5COSGeo4W%5Capache%5Chtdocs%5Cqgis_webclient%5Cprojects%5CBlumrodapark/Blumrodapark.qgs&maxExtent=1388389.0811664%2C6636775.183913%2C1389301.5481914%2C6637272.0245968).

Now I'd like to test out everything.
I tried to zoom in to the map, but it just stops by 1:2257 . I need more details.

I've checked the Settings in the **GlobalOptions.js**

```
    var MapOptions = {
  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection(authid),
  units: "m",
//  maxScale:50,
//  minScale:4000000,
  numZoomLevels:ZOOM_LEVELS,
  fractionalZoom: !enableWmtsBaseLayers && !enableBGMaps,
  transitionEffect:"resize",
  controls: []
```

I've tried to uncomment the max-/minscale and changed the values, but nothing works.

I hope you can help me to configure my new QGIS web-client.

(for example, I want to let the user zoom from 1:40000 to 1:50 [like here](https://webgis.uster.ch/maps/abfall/abfallentsorgung?format=image/jpeg&visibleLayers=Gemeindegrenze,Quartiere,Altstoffsammelstellen,Abfallbeh%C3%A4lter,Strassen%20nach%20Entsorgungsgebieten,Eisenbahn,Autobahn,Abfallentsorgungskreise,Pixelkarten%20und%20%C3%9Cbersichtsplan&searchtables=&startExtent=692000,241500,700100,249000&maxExtent=692000,241500,700100,249000).)

Answer (score 1):

You've found the correct part of code to change to your needs.

```
var MapOptions = {
  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection(authid),
  units: "m",
  maxScale:250,
  minScale:80000,
  numZoomLevels:ZOOM_LEVELS,
  fractionalZoom: !enableWmtsBaseLayers && !enableBGMaps, 
  transitionEffect:"resize",
  controls: []
};
```

I've copied this from my js file and I can zoom to 250. Now after all this intense configuration changes we simply refresh the web client and voila, the updated settings should be applied.